# Express two variables as one in this algebraic problem

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

[image]

"Maria wants to build a temple out of concrete. The temple consists of three walls and a ceiling, all of concrete. The walls and ceiling she makes are rectangular. There are some requirements to follow when building this temple (see the picture):

- The inner height of the temple is $2.4m$
- The ceiling's thickness is $0.40m$
- The back wall's thickness is $0.4m$
- The side walls have a thickness of $0.2m$
- The inner volume of the temple is $16m^3$

Maria wants to use as little concrete as possible. She assumes the back wall has a length of $x$ m. Describe a function that gives the volume of concrete needed as a function of $x$, thereafter, decide the least concrete possibly needed".

**Here's how far I've gotten:**

$a$ = lenght of side walls

- Volume of back wall: $2.4*0.40*x = 0.96x$
- Volume of side walls: $0.20*2.4*a = 0.48a$
- Volume of ceiling: $0.40*a*(0.4+x) = 0.16a + 0.4ax$

---

Total volume of concrete: $0.96x + 2*0.48a + 0.16a + 0.4ax = 0.96x + 1.12a + 0.4ax$

Inner volume: $x*(a-0.4)*2.4 = 2.4ax - 0.96x$

- $2.4ax - 0.96x = 16m^3$

---

- $2.4ax - 0.96x = 16m^3   => ax = (16/2.4)+(0.96x/2.4)$

---

- $a = (16/2.4x) + (0.96x/2.4x) = (16/2.4x) + 0.4$

---

- $0.96x + 0.64a + 0.4ax$
- $2.4ax - 0.96x = 16m3   => ax = (16/2.4)+(0.96x/2.4)$

---

- $0.4ax = 0.4((16/2.4)+(0.96x/2.4)) = 0.16x + (2+(2/3))$
- $0.96x + 0.64a + 0.4ax = 1.12x + (2+(2/3)) + 0.64a$

---

- $a = (16/2.4x) + (0.96x/2.4x) = (16/2.4x) + 0.4$
- $0.64a = 0.64((16/2.4x)+0.4)$
- $1.12x + (2+(2/3)) + 0.64a = 1.12x + 2(+(2/3)) + 0.64((16/2.4x)+0.4) ≈ 5.4x + 1.6$

---

- $f(x) = 5.4x + 1.6$   $(m^3)$

---

This is what I've tried.. but I'm stuck. How does one actually accomplish to come up with the correct answer? I think I've messed it up.

Comment: You're nearly there: $2.4 a x - 0.96 x = 16$. Therefore $2.4 a x = 16 + 0.96 x$ and therefore $a = \dots$. (I'd consider the inner length of the side walls, though, instead of the outer length; that looks a bit easier.)

Comment: @Magdiragdag  Hi! I've edited my answer and would be grateful if you could check it out.

Comment: Is $f(x)$ suppose to be the volume of the concrete as a function of the side of the back wall? $f(x) = 7.8x + 3$ can never be correct, for $f(x)$ would then increase without bound as you make $x$ larger and that is obviously not the case.

Comment: Something goes wrong in your computation. To simplify things, note that you might as well minimize the volume of the whole temple (since the inner volume is always 16) and hence you might as well minimize the ground area of the temple (since the height is always 2.4).

Comment: @Magdiragdag Not quite sure what you mean by that. How would I "minimize the ground area"? Have I gone with a wrong approach to this problem? Edit: Oh sorry! It's not the volume of the temple it's of the concrete! $f(x)$ gives us the volume of all the concrete needed. But what is it then that's gone wrong with my calculations if $5.4x + 1.6$ can't be true?

Comment: What is the definition of $f(x)$? I don't see $f$ mentioned before the last line. BTW you can use \implies and \iff for $\implies$ and $\iff$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok with your procedure till
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  Vc = 0.96\,x + 1.12\,a + 0.4\,a\,x \hfill \\
  Vi = 2.4\,a\,x - 0.96\,x = 16 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
then from the second we get 
$$
a = \frac{{16 + 0.96\,x}}
{{2.4\,x}} = \frac{{0.96}}
{{2.4}} + \frac{{16}}
{{2.4\,x}} = 0.4 + \frac{{20}}
{{3\,x}}
$$
which replaced in the first gives
$$
\begin{gathered}
  Vc_* (x) = 0.96\,x + 1.12\left( {0.4 + \frac{{20}}
{{3\,x}}} \right) + 0.4\,\left( {0.4 + \frac{{20}}
{{3\,x}}} \right)\,x =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{{4\left( {105\,x^{\,2}  + 292\,x + 700} \right)}}
{{375\,x}} = \frac{4}
{{375}}\left( {105\,x + 292\, + 700\frac{1}
{x}} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
which is the required function in $x$ to be minimized.
Then
$$
0 = \frac{d}
{{dx}}Vc_* (x) = 105\, - 700\frac{1}
{{x^{\;2} }}\quad  \to \quad x\, = \sqrt {\frac{{700}}
{{105}}}  \approx 2.58
$$
Therefore the minimization leads to the following values:
$$
x\, \approx 2.58\;m\quad a \approx 2.98\;m\quad Vc \approx 8.9\;m^3 
$$
Where did you go astray:  writing $(16/2.4x)$ which should actually been written $(16/(2.4x))$,
while in some passages -like in the last - you took as $(16/24) x$.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is correct, but you have a few mistakes in your calculations.

---

Let $g(a,x)=0.96x+1.12a+0.4ax$.

Then, you want to minimize $g(a,x)$ under the conditions
$$2.4ax-0.96x=16\quad \text{and}\quad x\gt 0\quad\text{and}\quad a\gt 0$$

For $x\gt 0$, we can have
$$2.4ax-0.96x=16\iff a=\frac{16}{2.4x}+\frac{0.96}{2.4}=\frac{20}{3x}+0.4$$

Therefore, you want to minimize
$$g(x)=0.96x+1.12\left(\frac{20}{3x}+0.4\right)+0.4x\left(\frac{20}{3x}+0.4\right)=1.12x+\frac{22.4}{3x}+\frac{9.344}{3}$$
for $x\gt 0$.

By AM-GM inequality, we have
$$g(x)=1.12x+\frac{22.4}{3x}+\frac{9.344}{3}\ge 2\sqrt{1.12x\times\frac{22.4}{3x}}+\frac{9.344}{3}=\color{red}{2\sqrt{\frac{25.088}{3}}+\frac{9.344}{3}\approx 8.898}$$
The equality is attained when $x=\sqrt{20/3}\approx 2.582$ and $a=0.4+\sqrt{20/3}\approx 2.982$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: the initial formulas that you obtained for the total volume of the concrete and for $a $ are correct. Now you can use them to substitute $a=16/(2.4 x) + 0.4 $ in the formula of the total volume of concrete. Then study the resulting function and search its minimum for positive values of $x $.